# Flutter: How to navigate to a new page from a generated List Tile?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

My problem is this child widget I'm calling will not push the change to the parent route so in it's own container when I have a onTap() => MaterialPageRoute(//) it will work but only in that container, the parent widget remains untouched. I'm also only using one route right now because I would like to solve that problem but I would like to assign a route to each list tile (see I'm iterating through a range to call it on index).

This is the instance in the parent class, adding onchanged and active didn't help.

```
Container(
         // alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            height: 400,
            width: 300,
            child:MyApp(active: _active,
        onChanged: _handleTapboxChanged,
      items: List<ListItem>.generate(
        FILLME.length,
        (i) => FILLME[i] != null
            ? MessageItem('${FILLME[i]}', 'Exercise')
            : MessageItem('Sender $i', 'Exercise'),

      ),
    ),
            ),
```

Here is my implementation of _HandleTapBoxChanged in the parent widget that worked in a different program to change the visibility of a widget from two different classes.

```
bool _active = false;

   void _handleTapboxChanged(bool newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _active = newValue;
    });
  }
```

active is bool instead of a variable for the route I want to pass because I can't define dynamic in the constructor of the child widget, it says fields must be final.

This is my whole class for my child widget.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ListItem> items;

  const MyApp({super.key,
    this.active = false,
    required this.onChanged,
 required this.items
 });
  


  
  final bool active;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

 // @override
 // void initState() {
 //   super.initState();
//  }
  
  
    void _moveState(context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HiFlutterApp()
            ),
            );
  }
  
  
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Agenda';

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.amber[100]
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body:
          ListView.builder(
          // Let the ListView know how many items it needs to build.
          itemCount: items.length,
          // Provide a builder function. This is where the magic happens.
          // Convert each item into a widget based on the type of item it is.
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final item = items[index];

            return ListTile(
              title: item.buildTitle(context),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline_sharp),
              subtitle: item.buildSubtitle(context),
              onTap:() => {_moveState(context)}
            );
          },
           
            //paranthese here
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

            

/// The base class for the different types of items the list can contain.
abstract class ListItem {
  /// The title line to show in a list item.
  Widget buildTitle(BuildContext context);

  /// The subtitle line, if any, to show in a list item.
  Widget buildSubtitle(BuildContext context);
  
  
}

/// A ListItem that contains data to display a heading.
class HeadingItem implements ListItem {
  final String heading;

  HeadingItem(this.heading);

  @override
  Widget buildTitle(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      heading,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSubtitle(BuildContext context) => const SizedBox.shrink();
}

/// A ListItem that contains data to display a message.
class MessageItem implements ListItem {
  final String sender;
  final String body;

  MessageItem(this.sender, this.body);

  @override
  Widget buildTitle(BuildContext context) => Text(sender);

  @override
  Widget buildSubtitle(BuildContext context) => Text(body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a few ListTiles with onTap Navigators you could have a list of the route names, and generate the list of widgets from there.

```
  List<String> routesNames = ['/route1', '/route2', '/route3'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: List.generate(
            routesNames.length,
            (index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text('ListTile $index'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, routesNames[index]);
                  },
                )),
      ),
    );
  }
```